# Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected Vector<R4>, got Vector<R8>

Tags: f#, ml.net

I am trying to write a basic 'hello world' type program to predict the values of the XOR function. This is the error message I am getting:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected Vector<R4>, got Vector<R8>
```

Parameter name: inputSchema
This is my code:

```
type Sample = {
    X: float
    Y: float
    Result: float
}

let createSample x y result = {X = x; Y = y; Result = result}

let solveXOR() =
    let problem = 
        [
            createSample 0.0 0.0 0.0
            createSample 1.0 0.0 1.0
            createSample 0.0 1.0 1.0
            createSample 1.0 0.0 0.0
        ]

    let context = new MLContext()
    let data = context.Data.ReadFromEnumerable(problem)

    let pipeline = 
        context.Transforms
            .Concatenate("Features", "X", "Y")
            .Append(context.Transforms.CopyColumns(inputColumnName = "Result", outputColumnName = "Label"))
            //.Append(context.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToVector("X"))
            //.Append(context.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToVector("Y"))
            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(context)
            .Append(context.Regression.Trainers.FastTree())

    let model = pipeline.Fit(data)

    let predictions = model.Transform(data)
    let metrics = context.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(predictions)

    printfn "Accuracy %f" metrics.Accuracy
```

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about  ml.net. Here is my wild guess it seems to be complaining about the size of  `float` numbers. A c# `float` is equivalent to an F# `float32` and a `double` is equivalent to an F# `float`. So try replacing your `float` with `float32`, and `0.0` with `0.0f`.

Comment: A `float32` is also called a `single` in F#

Comment: @AMieres, using a float32 / single was the answer! Could you please enter it as the answer so that it can get upvoted?

Comment: Ok, I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be complaining about the size of float numbers. A C# `float` is equivalent to an F# `float32` and a `double` is equivalent to an F# `float`. So try replacing your `float` with `float32` or `single`, and `0.0` with `0.0f`.

A `float32` is also called a `single` in F#

- C# `float` is equivalent to F# `single` or `float32`
- C# `double` is equivalent to F# `float` or `double`